# Error when accessing ESB Proxy with Jaggery WSStub

Tags: wso2, jaggery-js, wso2-esb

I created a web service and was able to send requests to it from a serverside Jaggery.js script with no problem. Then I created a WSDL Proxy Service inside WSO2 ESB and tested it using the "Try it!" feature.

After I redirected my serverside script from the original web service to its proxy inside ESB, I got the error in System Logs:

> The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is /services/BpmAdderProcessProxy.BpmAdderProcessProxyHttpSoap11Endpoint and the WSA Action = urn:anonOutInOpResponse. If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.

To see in detail what was happening I activated the "SOAP Message Tracer" of the ESB. Suddenly my serverside script could access the webservice via my ESB proxy. Then I deactivated the "SOAP Message Tracer" and the error message was back again. Is my serverside script correct? Or does the debugging tool modify behavior of debugged code?

I'm a JavaScript developer. Actually Jaggery and UES are targeted at people like me. I'm not supposed to look inside Java code, am I? Is there a forum where JavaScript developers discuss WSO2 UES and Jaggery?

My serverside code is as follows:

```
<%

var x = request.getParameter("x");
var y = request.getParameter("y");
//var sum = parseInt(x) + parseInt(y);
var sum = add(parseInt(x), parseInt(y));

response.content = {
    success: true,
    data: {
        result: sum
    }
};

function add(x, y) {

    var ws = require('ws');

    var stub = new ws.WSStub("http://02-128:8280/services/BpmAdderProcessProxy?wsdl");

    var process = stub.services["BpmAdderProcessProxy"].operations["process"];

    var payloadTemplate = process.payloadXML();

    var payload = replaceQuestionMarks(payloadTemplate, arguments);

    var resultXml = process.request(payload);

    var resultValue = resultXml.children().text();

    return parseInt(resultValue);


}

function replaceQuestionMarks(template, values) {

    var i = 0;

    return template.replace(
        /\?/g, 
        function() { 
            return values[i++]; 
        }
    );

}

%>
```

Comment: which version of wso2 esb are you using ? Can you change it's config ?

Comment: Jean-Michel, thank you for the comment. I'm using version 4.8.1 of wso2 esb and I can change it's config. I'm trying to get used to WSO2 products. Many things are new to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ESB v4.8.1, pass-through transport is enabled by default and it does not support SOAP body based dispatching (it does not build the message so it can't acces the body's first element to find the operation)

- You can append the operation name to the endpoint url : `http://host:8280/services/BpmAdderProcessProxy/OperationName`
- You can add this parameter in your proxy conf (BpmAdderProcessProxy) in WSO2 ESB : `<parameter name="disableOperationValidation" locked="false">true</parameter>`
- You can edit wso2esb/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml and replace `<handler class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.SOAPMessageBodyBasedDispatcher" name="SOAPMessageBodyBasedDispatcher"/>` 
  with 
  `<handler class="org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseSOAPMessageBodyBasedDispatcher" name="SOAPMessageBodyBasedDispatcher"/>`

Comment: Jean-Michel, the second option solved my problem. I opened the ESB Proxy Service config in the "Source View" mode and pasted the "parameter" element just below the opening "proxy" tag. After saving the config I disabled "SOAP Message Tracer" and tested my Jaggery script. It was working. Thanks a lot!